# how can i solve this issue from adsense

Tags: adsense

my website is http://howtolinuxs.com/ and connected with Blogger with good traffic. I applied for adsense application. but every time I received an email from google adsense that.

It’s important for sites displaying Google ads to offer significant value to the user. As a publisher, you must provide unique and relevant content that gives users a reason to visit your site first.
Don’t place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content.
Your site should also provide a good user experience through clear navigation and organization. Users should be able to easily click through your pages and find the information they’re seeking.
I only want to know that:

1. what the problem is and how I can fix this.

PLEASE REPLY ME AS SOON AS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply for Adsense through Earning Tab from Blogger.